# Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp\resources\views\projects\index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to retrieve data from my projects table according to forignId which is product_id. Here forignId comes from the product table where I add data using CURD in laravel which generates the requested id.
This is products table
[image]
This is my projects table.
[image]
This is index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Laravel 8 CRUD </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse flex-column">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <a class="btn btn-success text-light mr-5" data-toggle="medel" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModel"
                    data-attr="{{ route ('projects.create')}}" title="upload project">
                        <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>
                    <form action="{{ route('importProject') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="d-flex">
                        @csrf
                        <input type='file' name="file">

                        <button class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: -60px" title="Import Project">
                            <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt fa-2x"></i></button>

                            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ route('export') }}">Export User Data</a>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success text-light" data-toggle="modal" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModal"
                    data-attr="{{ route('projects.create') }}" title="Create a project"> <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-lg table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">No</th>
                <th scope="col">Chapter Name</th>
                <th scope="col" >Sub-Section Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Title 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Description 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Image 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Image 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Image 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Title 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Description 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Title 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Description 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Video 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Video 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Video 3</th>

                <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($projects as $project)
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row">{{ ++$i }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->chapter_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->sub_section_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->title_1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->description_1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->image_1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->image_2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->image_3 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->title_2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->description_2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->title_3 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->description_3 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->video_1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->video_2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->video_3 }}</td>

                    <td>{{ date_format($project->created_at, 'jS M Y') }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{{ route('projects.destroy', $project->id) }}" method="POST">

                            <a data-toggle="modal" id="smallButton" data-target="#smallModal"
                                data-attr="{{ route('projects.show', $project->id) }}" title="show">
                                <i class="fas fa-eye text-success  fa-lg"></i>
                            </a>

                            <a class="text-secondary" data-toggle="modal" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModal"
                                data-attr="{{ route('projects.edit', $project->id) }}">
                                <i class="fas fa-edit text-gray-300"></i>
                            </a>
                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE')

                            <button type="submit" title="delete" style="border: none; background-color:transparent;">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg text-danger"></i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

    {!! $projects->links() !!}


    <!-- small modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="smallModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="smallBody">
                    <div>
                        <!-- the result to be displayed apply here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- medium modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="mediumModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mediumModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="mediumBody">
                    <div>
                        <!-- the result to be displayed apply here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        // display a modal (small modal)
        $(document).on('click', '#smallButton', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let href = $(this).attr('data-attr');
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loader').show();
                },
                // return the result
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#smallModal').modal("show");
                    $('#smallBody').html(result).show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("Page " + href + " cannot open. Error:" + error);
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                timeout: 8000
            })
        });

        // display a modal (medium modal)
        $(document).on('click', '#mediumButton', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let href = $(this).attr('data-attr');
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loader').show();
                },
                // return the result
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#mediumModal').modal("show");
                    $('#mediumBody').html(result).show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("Page " + href + " cannot open. Error:" + error);
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                timeout: 8000
            })
        });

    </script>

@endsection
```

This is my projectController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exports\UsersExport;
use App\Models\Project;
use App\Imports\ProjectsImport;
use App\Models\Product;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\get;


class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {


        // $projects = Project::whereIn('product_id',Product::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id'))->latest()->paginate(20);


        // $products = Product::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id');
        $product = $request->input('id');
        // $projects = Project::where('product_id',$product)->pluck('id')->paginate(20);
        $projects = DB::table('projects')->pluck('product_id',$product);


        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }



    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('projects.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'chapter_name' => 'required',
            'sub_section_name' => 'required',
            'title_1' => 'required',
            'description_1' => 'required',
            'image_1' => 'required',
            'image_2' => 'required',
            'image_3' => 'required',
            'title_2' => 'required',
            'description_2' => 'required',
            'title_3' => 'required',
            'description_3' => 'required',
            'video_1' => 'required',
            'video_2' => 'required',
            'video_3' => 'required',
        ]);
        // $input = Project::whereIn('product_id',Product::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id'));
        $product = $request->input('id');
        $input = Project::where('product_id',$product);
        Project::create($input);
        return redirect()->route('project.index')
               >with('success','Product created successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Project $project)
    {
        return view('projects.show', compact('projects'));
    }

//     public function show(Product $product)
// {
//     return view('projects.show', [
//         'projects' => $product->projects()->latest()->paginate(20),
//     ]);
// }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Project $project)
    {
        return view('projects.edit', compact('projects'));
    }
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        // $user_id =  Auth::user()->id ;

        $request->validate([
            'chapter_name' => 'required',
            'sub_section_name' => 'required',
            'title_1' => 'required',
            'description_1' => 'required',
            'image_1' => 'required',
            'image_2' => 'required',
            'image_3' => 'required',
            'title_2' => 'required',
            'description_2' => 'required',
            'title_3' => 'required',
            'description_3' => 'required',
            'video_1' => 'required',
            'video_2' => 'required',
            'video_3' => 'required',
        ]);

        // $input = $request->all();

        $product = $request->input('id');
        $input = Project::where('product_id',$product);

        $project->update($input);

        return redirect()->route('project.index')
                        ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
    }
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Project $project)
    {
        $project->delete();

        return redirect()->route('projects.index')
            ->with('success', 'Project deleted successfully');
    }

    public function importProject()
    {
        Excel::import(new ProjectsImport, request()->file('file'));

        return back()->with('success','Project created successfully.');
    }

    public function export()
    {
        return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'projects.xlsx');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

You need to call paginate() method (or simplePaginate() or cursorPaginate()) on your builder (thanks @lagbox) in order to use links() method in your blade template.

**EDIT:**
If I understand your example correctly, I would edit ProjectController@index like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $productId = $request->input('id');
    $projects = Project::where('product_id', $productId)->paginate(15);


    return view('projects.index')->with(
            [
                'projects' => $projects,
                'i' => ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5
            ]
        );
}
```

Then, place `{{ $projects->links() }}` in index.blade.php file.

However, there's much more to refactor in the ProjectController file, for example this nonsense in the store method:

```
$input = Project::where('product_id',$product);
Project::create($input);
```

Comment: those methods would be called on a Builder not a Collection

Comment: see i am a beginner on Laravel i have add this code {!! $projects->links() !!} but still not working. From you ans i can`t solve the problem

Comment: @AbdullahAlShahed I edited my answer, please check. I would also recommend you to check these docs - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections (especially the pluck() method)

Comment: ok but it's not giving me what I want. Here I am uploading an excel file in the projects table. projects table have a row called product_id. which is requested id from products table. If requested id is 3 than in index.blade.php will show all data of requested id 3 from projects table. which in not happening. For this purpose i used pluck function